# Is immutable variable thread safe in this case?

Tags: c#, multithreading, immutability

Considering the following code sample, the variable `i` is of an immutable `int` type. After incrementing `i`, the new value is stored on the same memory location. So if multiple threads are reading from that location, some of them may get corrupted data at the moment when writing is in progress. How is this immutable type thread safe then? Is there any internal CLR logic that takes care of that?

```
public class Test
{
    int i = 10;

    public unsafe int Run()
    {
        fixed (int* ip = &i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"address of i before updation: {((IntPtr)ip).ToString()}");
        }

        i = i + 1;

        fixed (int* ipNew = &i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"address of i after updation: {((IntPtr)ipNew).ToString()}");
        }

        return i;
    }
}
```

**Update:** 
I updated the code, based on comments as I was not clear before. Now what if, class `Test` is initiated once by client and `Run` method is called by multiple thread. Will `i` be considered thread safe?

Comment: Immutability is not a guarantee to thread safety, even if you could read and write atomically you will still stale variables and data race condition. also the game changes totally when you are using pointers. just lock anything you need, problem solved

Comment: It is a local variable, the usual simplification is that it is "allocated on the stack".  Every thread has its own stack, so no sharing can ever occur.  And is therefore always thread-safe.

Comment: @HansPassant you are right, just updated the answer to make it a global class level instance. What will happen then?

Comment: Then you have a bug, any value of 10 or higher is possible.  Not so easy to observe btw, the Console.WriteLine() statement takes a lock to keep the console thread-safe and that has a knack for causing accidental synchronization.  Tends to go wrong once a week, give or take.  Don't write code you cannot possibly debug.

Comment: @TheGeneral but people strongly relate these two concepts, everywhere I read, they state the main point of immutability is that its inherently thread safe.

Comment: @Saad I think you are more asking about thread safety of atomic operations, Immutablity does not matter if the operations you are performing are not performed in an atomic way. `i = i + 1;` is not an atomic operation without putting a lock around it.

Comment: In Safe code I'd use the Volatile keyword to create thread safe access to a scalar.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that's what I'll do with mutable types, but what's with the claim of immutable being thread safe then?

Comment: Since when has `int` been an immutable type?

Comment: @HansPassant I'm printing only the variable address just for testing purpose as a proof that memory address after update is same. My concern is, why during read, `i` won't be corrupted if another thread is writing on its memory location. Is there any internal lock?

Comment: It will get corrupted, just not when you want it to happen.  Such is the nature of threading race bugs, they don't happen often enough and strike randomly.  A thread needs to be bumped out of its usual execution pattern, that typically requires having other programs running and also demanding service from the OS.  Watch [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/CHESS-An-Automated-Concurrency-Testing-Tool).

Comment: @JohnWu since always. Tell me one property or field of a `int` you are able to modify.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Name one you can't .

Comment: @JohnWu [`m_value`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,e684b180141a1959)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your update, no the code will not be thread safe. You are reading i, incrementing the value, then writing to i. These three steps are not one unit of logic, other threads can interact with i in between the read and write steps.

For example, you have three threads, A B and C. Something happens that makes B run slower than the other threads.

```
A: Read i to thread local memory location A the value 10
B: Read i to thread local memory location B the value 10
A: Add 1 to thread local memory location A
A: Write 11 to i from thread local memory location A
B: Add 1 to thread local memory location B
C: Read i to thread local memory location C the value 11
C: Add 1 to thread local memory location C
C: Write 12 to i from thread local memory location C
B: Write 11 to i from thread local memory location B
```

Because the 3 operations where not "atomic" the 3 threads could do work inbetween the 3 steps B had to perform, this causes you to have a wrong ending value.

The normal way to handle this is either lock around the 3 operations so only a single thread can do it at once,

```
lock(someObject)
{
   i = i + 1;
}
```

use a tool that makes the operation atomic

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref i);
```

or check that the value of i had not changed between the start of the read and the write you want to perform and if it did change retry the operation.

```
int iOriginal, iNew;
do 
{
    iOriginal = i;
    iNew = iOriginal + 1;
} while(iOriginal != Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref i, iNew, iOriginal)
```

The reason people say immutable values are thread safe is they are referring to passing a copy of the reference to another function, once the copy of that reference is made you don't need to worry about another thread changing the value of that object while you are working with it. But if you are not making a copy of the reference (like in your example where you used a shared variable outside of the scope of the function) you run in to problems of the non-immutability of the reference you are using between threads.

In simpler terms, the value 10 is immutable, the variable with the name `i` is not. If you share the variable (I am not talking about the object refrence/value the variable has but the variable itself) across threads then you are working with a mutable object.

Comment: Suppose when thread A was writing after incrementing, thread C was reading at exactly the same time. In that very moment, A is trying to make a copy of `i` and saving it on same memory location. What will thread C read then? or is there internal low level lock to access memory locations?

Comment: writes of 32 bit values are atomic operations on all platforms the CLI supports, that is part of the specification. See section 10.6 of [the C# specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf), so I guess the answer to that part is yes, the CLI does do some magic to ensure you don't get torn reads or writes to anything that is on the list of atomic operations from the spec. If you where using a `long` instead of a `int` and you where on a 32 bit operating system then you could get half written values, aka "torn"

Comment: I think it answers my question. One more thing, you said _passing a copy of the reference to another function_ ? Isn't the copy of reference gets passed by mutable or reference types? such as class instances or lists? I think in this case, it's safe to say that the whole value is copied on new location on the stack i.e. the called function doesn't even know about any previous references.

Comment: You need to seperate in your mind the variable and the value the variable represents. For a struct like a int the variable holds the memory representation of the struct. For a reference like a list the variable holds the address in memory to find the object data of the reference. When you pass in a variable to a function the value of the variable gets copied to the new function, that value could be the memory representation of the object like in a struct, or it could be that address in memory to find the object like in a class. With a immutable object you know that once you have a copy ...

Comment: ... of that value the variable held you know that the "thing" that variable is representing will not be modified. The problem your code had was the threads do not get their own copy of the variable's value, they all shared a single variable which could be changed. If you wanted to make this work and make the variable immutable with shared threads you would need to declare the variable `readonly int i = 10;` so the variable itself became immutable too.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, for your help. I still have few reservations but I guess I need to do some in depth reading to clear further doubts. Cheers!